# discord.js log last 10 messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have the following code:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const { token } = require('./config.json');
const { general } = require('./config.json');
const { guild } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready!");

  channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 10 })
  .then(messages => console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`))
  .catch(console.error);
});

client.login(token);
console.log("Online")
```

But when I run the code I always get this error:

```
ReferenceError: channel is not defined
at Client.<anonymous> (/workspaces/proJM-bridge/index.js:14:3)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (/workspaces/proJM-bridge/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:385:17)
at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (/workspaces/proJM-bridge/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:368:10)
at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (/workspaces/proJM-bridge/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:194:14)
at WebSocketShard.emit (node:events:513:28)
at WebSocketShard.checkReady (/workspaces/proJM-bridge/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:511:12)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/workspaces/proJM-bridge/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:483:16)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/workspaces/proJM-bridge/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:320:10)
```

I can't find anywhere what is wrong and I have tried many code and still get the same error. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

config.json:

```
{
"token": "Token hidden",
"general": "1028589311282647041",
"guild": "1028241554277679236"
}
```

Comment: First of all, please post your config file. Second of all, it's impossible to store a function (in your case `channel.messages.fetch`) in a JSON file, which is simply a data format. Finally, why not import `token`, `channel`, and `guild` all at the same time instead of importing three separate times from the same file?

Comment: Sorry for not posting I'm going to edit the post with it

Comment: I changed the variable name and now I get a different error: `
ReferenceError: channel is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspaces/proJM-bridge/index.js:21:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47`

Comment: I also am very new to java script so I don't know how to import them all at once.

Comment: The error tells you all need to know. `channel` is undefined, so you will have to put that code in a `messageCreate` event or in the `ready` event

Comment: If `channel` is a snowflake, how do you expect it to have a `messages` property? And you can only fetch channels when the bot is already logged in, so as @Caladan mentioned, you need to move your code to an event listener, like `messageCreate`, or `ready`. The https://discordjs.guide is a good source to learn more about the basics of discord.js.

Comment: What is a snowflake? Sorry as I said I'm very new to javascript and discord.js

Comment: I have added the new code/changes and now I get a new error. How do I define "channel"

Comment: Try adding this `const channel = client.channels.cache.get('channel-id')` inside the `ready` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need this block:

```js
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const { general } = require('./config.json');
const { guild } = require('./config.json');
```

You can write it in one line:

```
const { token, general, guild } = require('./config.json');
```

And you can fix the error with just defining `channel` + I think you also need to add the `GuildMessages` intent to your bot.

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, TextChannel } = require('discord.js');

const { token } = require('./config.json');
const { general } = require('./config.json');
const { guild } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
});

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready!");

    /**
     * @type {TextChannel}
     */
    const channel = client.guilds.cache.get(guild).channels.cache.get(general);
    if(!channel) return console.log('Invalid guildId or channelId');

    channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 10 })
    .then(messages => {
        messages.forEach((m) => {
            const content = m.content ? m.content : `<No Message Content>`;
            const embeds = m.embeds ? `<${m.embeds.length} Embed(s)>` : `<No embeds>`;
            const attachments = m.attachments ? `<${m.attachments.size} Attachment(s)>` : `<No Attachments>`;

            console.log(`---------------------------\nAuthor: ${m.author.tag}\nContent: ${content}\nEmbeds: ${embeds}\nAttachments: ${attachments}\n---------------------------`);
        });        
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});

client.login(token);
```

I also removed the `console.log` in the last line bc it's completely useless as you already have one in the ready event.

Comment: This worked great thanks so much! One question though, I am trying to use `console.log` to log the messages. What name are the messages saved under?

Comment: wdym by that? the messages are not saved just because you log them..

Comment: I want to be able to read the past 10 messages in the console.

Comment: edited it, didn't test it, lemme know if it doesn't work

Comment: I just got a bunch of empty spaces in the console but thanks for trying. I want something like this in the console: `wumpus#0001: hello` but it's not just one message instead it's ten.

Comment: yea i also edited the Client intents, you have to add the `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` intent, please update that. at the moment you're reading this i also edited it, so messages are logged like `wumpus#0001: hello`

Comment: I get an error: `Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted.` Do I just need to give the bot some perms or is it a code error?

Comment: You have to go to your Application in the Developer portal then go to the Bot tab and unter **Privileged Gateway Intents** you have to activate all 3 switches

Comment: Ok, I will do that. I will tell you if that works.

Comment: Works great and messages appear with no problems/errors. The only thing is that I can't see who sent what message but if that's too hard then don't worry I can just deal with it.

Comment: no it's not complicated I just edited it. could you also mark my reply as the accepted answer because i need that reputation... ty ^^

Comment: Done thanks so much, I hope I wasn't asking took much from you. The code works with no problem.

Comment: The messages are listed newest at the top and oldest at the bottom which I would like the other way around but I think I could do that myself.

Comment: Images also don't show but that makes sense but is it possible to have it log something like <image> when there is an image so I know?

Comment: edited the code, should display every message as
---------------------------
Author: <Tag>
Content: <Message content>
Embeds: <Embed amount>
Attachments: <Attachment amount>
---------------------------

Comment: Ok I thought that would not be possiable but ok I'll try it

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, you have helped me a lot and without I would have most likely given up. If there is any way I can get you any more reputation please tell me.

Comment: no problem, you don't have to give me more reputation. i'm happy with you being happy :)

Comment: Well then we are good and the question can be closed.